# Citing sources within table and figure legends

Tags: academic-writing, scientific-publishing

I have a figure and a table within my results section that contains data I used software to collect. I have already cited this software within my paper, but to allow my figures to stand on their own I feel as if I need to cite the software in the legends, too.

How would I go about this? Should I include the full reference? Or would an author and a date suffice?

I'm using Harvard referencing style (author/date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A citation would follow the same format regardless of whether it's in a table or figure legend or the body of the text. In no instance would your citation be more than author and date.

That said, for data citations, it's not clear what you mean by "data I used software to collect." In general, you would only cite published datasets and not software that was used to collect the data (so, for example, if your data was a set of temperature measurements you collected with a program that read from a digital thermometer connected to your computer, you wouldn't cite the program). Published data, on the other hand would have either a DOI or URL that you could refer to in your reference list.